# Script for awscli check not working with crontab schedule

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, root, unicode

I have written a small code snippet to check the aws cli version

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    if [ -e "/usr/local/bin/aws" ];
    then
        myAWS="/usr/local/bin/aws"
    else
        myAWS="/usr/bin/aws"
    fi
    
    myCmd=("${myAWS} --version")
    
    echo "$myCmd"
    
    message=$($myCmd)

echo "$message"
```

Now while running this manually with root user I am able to run this script without any issue . Post our aws cli upgrade when we try to schedule this script via crontab for root user ( schedule given below)

57 21 * * * /rough/scripts/log/test.sh > /rough/scripts/log/test.log 2>&1

I face the below error , can you suggest??? I have reinstalled the aws cli but to no effect.

I understand crontab runtime environment is different than when you run a script manually but can I check whats the runtime environment that cronjob picks up. The user is root and OS is SLES.

[[Error as below]]

```
/usr/local/bin/aws --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "awscli/help.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "docutils/core.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "docutils/io.py", line 43, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 4-6: surrogates not allowed
[24036] Failed to execute script 'aws' due to unhandled exception!`
```

Comment: Wild guess, you're mixing different python versions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller- I read this somewhere that the python version used by aws cli and the os python version is interdependent , the problem is  for all my other servers it works fine having a different awscli python version and os python version. I am struggling to find a clue since yesterday :(

Comment: Saving the output to $message and then echoing it later is dumb.  Just run without saving the output unless you're going to use that output.  echo is a bit dangerous to just stuff random output on its command line.

Comment: The last line in your output (unicode error) is incomplete.  There should be something informative right after that that is the real error.  But I'd guess that the input has a malformed unicode entity in it.   Without knowing what this is, I can't say if this is a bug in your input or poor error handling in the code.  It is possible to tell python how to handle bad unicode so you don't get this error.

Comment: redirect:  You're right, I misread that as 2> /dev/null idunno why.  Must be asleep.

Comment: Hi @user10489- I need the output to be echoed as part of another requirement , regardless , any suggestions as to why this is coming up as an error only via crontab and not when i run it manually ? Also I just pasted the entire output , thats the entire error  i get .